# Machine Level Representation

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm doing this project and this particular portion is confusing me. We are given this machine level representation and it will read six numbers that I have to figure out. So far I know that this is a loop and it will iterate until it reaches it's stop clause. We do not want it to ever make the call to explode at 0x08048d3a : call 0x80492f3 . Does anyone know what six numbers are going to be generated. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
0x08048d0b <phase_2+0>:         push   %ebp
0x08048d0c <phase_2+1>:         mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048d0e <phase_2+3>:         push   %esi
0x08048d0f <phase_2+4>:         push   %ebx
0x08048d10 <phase_2+5>:         sub    $0x30,%esp
0x08048d13 <phase_2+8>:         lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d16 <phase_2+11>:        mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048d1a <phase_2+15>:        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d1d <phase_2+18>:        mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048d20 <phase_2+21>:        call   0x8049335 <read_six_numbers>
0x08048d25 <phase_2+26>:        mov    $0x2,%ebx
0x08048d2a <phase_2+31>:        lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi
0x08048d2d <phase_2+34>:        mov    -0x8(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
0x08048d31 <phase_2+38>:        add    $0x5,%eax
0x08048d34 <phase_2+41>:        cmp    %eax,-0x4(%esi,%ebx,4)
0x08048d38 <phase_2+45>:        je     0x8048d3f <phase_2+52>
0x08048d3a <phase_2+47>:        call   0x80492f3 <explode_bomb>
0x08048d3f <phase_2+52>:        add    $0x1,%ebx
0x08048d42 <phase_2+55>:        cmp    $0x7,%ebx
0x08048d45 <phase_2+58>:        jne    0x8048d2d <phase_2+34>
0x08048d47 <phase_2+60>:        add    $0x30,%esp
0x08048d4a <phase_2+63>:        pop    %ebx
0x08048d4b <phase_2+64>:        pop    %esi
0x08048d4c <phase_2+65>:        pop    %ebp
0x08048d4d <phase_2+66>:        ret
```

Specifically can you explain what happens at these lines

```
0x08048d10 <phase_2+5>:         sub    $0x30,%esp
0x08048d13 <phase_2+8>:         lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d16 <phase_2+11>:        mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048d1a <phase_2+15>:        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d1d <phase_2+18>:        mov    %eax,(%esp)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: why drop the homework and x86 tags?

Comment: You should consider solving some problems on http://crackmes.de/ .

Comment: We're happy to help with homework, but you're asking for the answer.  We don't do that.  Can you ask a more specific question? (how to interpret `jne    0x8048d2d <phase_2+34>` etc?

Comment: I'd get a whiteboard and divide it into chunks, keeping the value of each register in one chunk of the whiteboard as you step through and follow the execution. If there's a specific part you don't know what the effects of it then ask for help on that.

Comment: Why is there a "(C)" in the question title?  The question has nothing to do with either C or copyright.

Answer (score 2):

This AT&T syntax confuses me, but this part is simple:

```
0x08048d10 <phase_2+5>:         sub    $0x30,%esp //reserve additional 0x30bytes 12 ints) on the stack
0x08048d13 <phase_2+8>:         lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax // int vals[6]; eax = vals;
0x08048d16 <phase_2+11>:        mov    %eax,0x4(%esp) // int some_local_var = vals;
0x08048d1a <phase_2+15>:        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax // first param we received
0x08048d1d <phase_2+18>:        mov    %eax,(%esp) // pass it as param to function
0x08048d20 <phase_2+21>:        call   0x8049335 <read_six_numbers>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char answer[6];
answer[0] = any_char
for n > 0
answer[n] = answer[n-1] + 5;
```